# Unsupported operand types Error. When paypal return after payment?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

**i am getting error**
Unsupported operand types in /home4/moses/public_html/mywebsite.com/ipn-page-template.php on line 27.

**My all code on ipn page.**

```
$url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

// Set up request to PayPal
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($request, array
(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array('cmd' => '_notify-validate') + $ipn_post_data),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',
));

// Execute request and get response and status code
$response = curl_exec($request);
$status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Close connection
curl_close($request);

if($status == 200 && $response == 'VERIFIED')
{
    $subject = "valid";
    $message = "good";
}
else
{
    $subject = "invalid";
    $message = "bad";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure $ipn_post_data is defined and is an array?

Answer (score 0):

check the return values of these 2 - make sure they are strings/ints/bools and not something more complex like an array or object

```
var_dump($response);
var_dump($status);
```